# How do I determine what technology has been used for a website backend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image-processing, web

just out of curiosity, I was wondering if its possible to determine what technology has been used for a website backend?

I stumbled upon this (http://propercloth.com/custom-dress-shirts/) website and was wondering what have they used for the image processing part where the shirt image is generated on selecting the desired fabric. Is it matlab or can anyone suggest any image processing technology which can be used to create a similar functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the client server communication I strongly believe that this is a well prepared composition of images, not an automated search. So there's definitely no need for MatLab here, just a database, jquery, some server side scripting and a hell lot of images.

If you need live search of fabrics you might take a look at OpenCV (computer vision framework), TinEye (similar image search service), LIRE (library for sontent based image retrieval), etc.

[image: Network communication in Chrome]

Comment: Yes, I did see this image too, but after selecting a different fabric, this image is replaced with the one matching the selected fabric. That is why I think there is a backend image processing to it, I might be wrong though.

Comment: As far as I see it's just ~ 350 different fabrics. A taxonomy or relation would be totally feasible (and much better than content based texture and color matching).